# scala language not avaible?

Tags: programming

For another course I need the scala programming language. 
Is it right it's not avaible on the software center?
if that is so, what is the best way to install it.

Roelof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scala is available to be installed using the software center.

[image: scala]

Type "software sources" in the dash and open the application

[image: software sources]

and check if you tick marks as the following image:

[image: universal sources]

Comment: found it. I had to choose a server.